# Why won't this generic java code compile?

Tags: java, generics

In this simplified example I have a generic class, and a method that returns a Map regardless of the type parameter.  Why does the compiler wipe out the types on the map when I don't specify a type on the containing class?

```
import java.util.Map;

public class MyClass<T>
{
    public Map<String, String> getMap()
    {   
        return null;
    }

    public void test()
    {   
        MyClass<Object> success = new MyClass<Object>();
        String s = success.getMap().get("");

        MyClass unchecked = new MyClass();
        Map<String, String> map = unchecked.getMap();  // Unchecked warning, why?
        String s2 = map.get("");

        MyClass fail = new MyClass();
        String s3 = fail.getMap().get("");  // Compiler error, why?
    }
}
```

I get this compiler error.

```
MyClass.java:20: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String
                String s3 = fail.getMap().get("");  // Compiler error
```

Comment: What is the exact text of the unchecked warning?

Comment: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Got it. This actually *isn't* a bug, strange as it might seem.

From [section 4.8 (raw types) of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#110257):

> The type of a constructor (§8.8),
>   instance method (§8.8, §9.4), or
>   non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw
>   type C that is not inherited from its
>   superclasses or superinterfaces is the
>   erasure of its type in the generic
>   declaration corresponding to C. The
>   type of a static member of a raw type
>   C is the same as its type in the
>   generic declaration corresponding to
>   C.

So even though the method's type signature doesn't use any type parameters of the class itself, type erasure kicks in and the signature becomes effectively

```
public Map getMap()
```

In other words, I think you can imagine a raw type as being the same API as the generic type but with all `<X>` bits removed from *everywhere* (in the API, not the implementation).

EDIT: This code:

```
MyClass unchecked = new MyClass();
Map<String, String> map = unchecked.getMap();  // Unchecked warning, why?
String s2 = map.get("");
```

compiles because there's an implicit but unchecked conversion from the raw `Map` type to `Map<String, String>`. You can get the same effect by making an explicit conversion (which does nothing at execution time) in the last case:

```
// Compiles, but with an unchecked warning
String x = ((Map<String, String>)fail.getMap()).get("");
```

Comment: Hm ... it kind of makes sense ... but it's incredibly stupid at the same time ...

Answer (score 5):

Hm ... unfortunately I can't tell you why it fails. But I can give you a simple workaround:

Change the type of `fail` to `MyClass<?>`, then it will compile just fine.

Comment: A cast works just fine too.  Why would a type of ? affect the type of the map?  It still makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Motlin: Jon explained it pretty well: MyClass<?> is not a raw type.

Comment: Now that I understand why your workaround works, I'm going to use it instead of a cast.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting question, and very interesting answer by Jon Skeet.

I just want to add something about the stupidity or not stupidity of this behaviour of the java compiler.

I think that the compiler assumes that **if you don't specify the type parameter in a generc class you are not able (or don't want to) use any type parameter at all**. You could use a version of java earlier than 5, or love to make casts manually.

It doesn't seem so stupid to me.

Answer (score 1):

Generic types get erased after compiling.

When you do:

```
Map<String, String> map = unchecked.getMap();
```

you're forcing a cast from Map to Map<String, String>, and that's why the unchecked warning. However, after that you can do:

```
String s2 = map.get("");
```

because map is of type Map<String, String>.

However, when you do

```
String s3 = fail.getMap().get("");
```

you're not casting fail.getMap() to anything, so it's considered to be plainly Map, not Map<String, String>.

What you should do in the latter is something like:

```
String s3 = ((Map<String, String>fail.getMap()).get("");
```

which will still thrown a warning but will work anyway.

Comment: Then why does the first one compile?  "Erasure" isn't the full answer here.