# Raw types with generic methods independent of the generic type

Tags: java, generics

This a follow-up to [chrert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658772/chrert)'s question [Generic classes with Collection getter of other types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654561/generic-classes-with-collection-getter-of-other-types/16654735). If you can come up with a better title to my question, feel free to edit it:

Following code contains a generic class `GenericClass<T>` with a method of return type `T` and another method with return type `Collection<String>`, which is obviously independent of `T`.

Now, if I instantiate a raw `GenericClass` (which I would never do, so this question is more a theoretical question, to help understand what's going on) then calling that method in an enhanced for loop won't work, because all generic type information seem to get lost when using raw types. But then, when calling that same method in an assignment, it works (it warns about type unsafety, but it compiles).

In my point of view, either both shouldn't work, or both should work. I don't understand why one works, and the other doesn't. Do you have any hints, or know any parts of the JLS that explain this behavior?

```
public class GenericClass<T>  {

    T doSomething() {
        return null;
    }

    Collection<String> getCollection() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericClass raw = new GenericClass();
        // This will not compile (Error message below)
        for (String str : raw.getCollection()) {
            // Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String
        }
        // This is only a warning:
        // Type safety: The expression of type Collection needs unchecked conversion to conform to Collection<String>
        Collection<String> coll = raw.getCollection();
        for (String string : coll) {
            // works just fine
        }
    }
}
```

---

There is a related question, which, together with the accepted answer here, explains what's going on pretty good: [Why won't this generic java code compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662191/why-wont-this-generic-java-code-compile)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, `raw.getCollection()` returns a raw `Collection`.  [JLS 14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) specifies the type checking for the enhanced `for` loop:

> If Type (in the FormalParameter production) is a reference type, then TargetType is Type; otherwise, TargetType is the upper bound of the capture conversion of the type argument of I, **or Object if I is raw.**

(emphasis added)

In the second case, you're explicitly assigning a raw type to a generic type, which is allowed with a warning like normal.

Comment: The emphasis and explanation of the second case make it perfectly clear. Thank you!