# Generics compile issue: incompatible types

Tags: java, generics

Given this simple class:

```
    import java.util.Collection;

    public class GenericTest<T> {
      public Collection<String> getKeys() {
        return null;
      }
      public void copy(GenericTest a_from) {
        for (String x : a_from.getKeys()) {

        }
      }
    }
```

I am getting the following compile error, but don't understand why.

```
    error: incompatible types
    for (String x : a_from.getKeys()) {
      required: String
      found:    Object
```

The error goes away if I change the parameter to the copy() method to GenericTest<T>, but that is not what I want.  The copy() method is valid on any type of GenericTest, not just GenericTest<T>.

Comment: Where is `a_from` declared?

Comment: a_from is declared in the signature of the copy() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you create a generic class. If you use a raw type of your generic class, then all the parameterized type used inside the class, loose their type information. So, for `GenericTest` raw type, the `getKeys()` method signature changes to:

```
public Collection getKeys() {
    return null;
}
```

So, if you iterate over `getKeys()` method of `GenericTest` raw type, you will get `Object`, and not `String`, which I don't see why you expect.

From [JLS Section 4.8 - Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

---

You should really use `GenericTest<T>` as parameter type in your method, instead of raw type. And change the return type of `getKeys` to `Collection<T>`.

Change your class to:

```
public class GenericTest<T> {
    public Collection<T> getKeys() {
      return null;
    }
    public void copy(GenericTest<T> a_from) {
      for (T x : a_from.getKeys()) {

      }
   }
}
```

The type `T` is infered from the parameterized type you create for this generic class. For `GenericTest<String>`, `T` will be infered as `String`, in your class.

---

**Reference:**

- [Angelika Langer - Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [How to define Generic Type](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ002)

Comment: But the getKeys() method really does return a Collection of String, not T. (The example here is pared down from my actual class, just to show the error condition.)

Comment: @Mitch. In that case, use `GenericTest<String>` as method parameter. But I don't see any reason you would make your class generic at all.

Comment: My confusion was that the compiler changes the return type of the getKeys() method, even though I want it to be String.  Just goes to show there is always more to learn!

Comment: @Mitch. Hmm. You should go through the link I posted at the end of my answer. That is the best generics reference you will get.

Answer (score 1):

you might wanted to write

```
public void copy(GenericTest<String> a_from) {
```

or

```
public void copy(GenericTest<T> a_from) {
```

this looked odd to me too,
explanation here (this is a duplicate):
[Why won't this generic java code compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662191/why-wont-this-generic-java-code-compile)

Comment: See my original post.  The copy() method is valid for any type of GenericTest, not just those of type T.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want:

```
public void copy(GenericTest<?> a_from) {
    for (String x : a_from.getKeys()) {

    }
}
```

This would accept any generic type, as per your request.

I modified your class, just so it wouldn't return a `null` collection, and I made the `for` loop print the strings read.
This is the result, which compiles (and runs) just fine.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GenericTest<T> {
    public Collection<String> getKeys() {
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        a.add("1");
        a.add("2");
        a.add("3");
        return a;
    }

    public void copy(GenericTest<?> a_from) {
        for (String x : a_from.getKeys()) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

    public static void testIt() {
        GenericTest<Integer> gti = new GenericTest<Integer>();
        GenericTest<String> gts = new GenericTest<String>();

        gts.copy(gti);
    }
}
```