# Java 8 needs a cast while Java 7 didn't - enum.getClass/getDeclaringClass

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I realise Java 8 is still in Beta but this one struck me as odd:

```
public class Fields<C extends Enum<C>> {

    public Fields(Set<C> columns) {
        // A sample column used to find the universe of the enum of Columns.
        C sampleCol = columns.iterator().next();
        // Java 8 needs a cast here.
        Set<C> allColumns = EnumSet.allOf((/*Class<C>)*/ sampleCol.getClass());
        // ... there's more to this that I've deleted.
    }

}
```

The error reads:

```
error: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
            Set<C> allColumns = EnumSet.allOf(sampleCol.getClass());
    inferred: C
    equality constraints(s): C,CAP#1
  where C is a type-variable:
    C extends Enum<C> declared in class Test.Fields
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Enum from capture of ? extends Enum
```

Is this a bug or a new feature of Java 8?

Comment: I tried  it with Java 7(51) and Java 8(b128) and in both cases compiler required cast, of course still in warning in both cases. But when I remove casting I get error in both cases(Java 7,8). I tried it in IDEA 13 environment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Interesting, this is a subtle change in the treatment of [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

First, let's clarify your example. The return type of [`Object.getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) is special:

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is called.

In this case, `X` would be the type parameter `C`, which [erases](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) to `Enum`. So `sampleCol.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends Enum>`. [`EnumSet.allOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf%28java.lang.Class%29) declares the type parameter `E extends Enum<E>`, and in your case `? extends Enum` is being inferred as its type argument.

The important part is that `Enum` is a raw type. The use of raw types has been seen to erase seemingly unrelated generics, for example on this post: [Why won't this generic java code compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662191/why-wont-this-generic-java-code-compile) In his answer there, Jon Skeet cites [JLS §4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) ("Raw Types") to cover this unintuitive behavior.

Similar behavior seems to be happening in your example with Java 7: `EnumSet.allOf(sampleCol.getClass())` is allowed to compile with an "unchecked invocation" warning (this gets hidden by the subsequent "unchecked conversion" warning from assigning the resulting raw `EnumSet` to `Set<C>`).

The question becomes: should the occurrence of a raw type in a generic wildcard's bounds allow unchecked conversions? JLS §4.8 makes no mention of this, so it's ambiguous. Possibly it's a bug, but it seems like a reasonable tightening of this behavior. While a standard raw type like `Enum` might itself be expected from legacy APIs, a "half-baked" type like `Class<? extends Enum>` could only occur post-generics and so it doesn't really make sense to let it disrupt generic type checking.

Anyway I'm interested to see if anyone can point to documentation about this change - my search didn't turn anything up.

---

**About your specific code:** you should use [`getDeclaringClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#getDeclaringClass%28%29) instead. The compiler can't know that calling `getClass` on a `C` will return exactly `Class<C>`; in fact, it won't if used on an enum with a constant-specific class. This is exactly the use case for which `Enum` declares that method.

Comment: Thank you for the insights and the solution - very interesting. Strangely that is the second time this week I've needed to use `getDeclaringClass` - each in totally different circumstances. I've never needed it before.