# Collection becomes a raw type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

For example we have some AbsractClass

```
package inherit;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * TODO: Add comment
 *
 * @author Ruslan Ibragimov
 */
public abstract class AbstractClass<T extends Integer> {

    private Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>();

    private T value;

    public Set<String> getStrings() {
        return strings;
    }

    public void setStrings(Set<String> strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
    }

    public void addString(String string) {
        strings.add(string);
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And some child:

```
package inherit;

/**
 * TODO: Add comment
 *
 * @author Ruslan Ibragimov
 */
public class InheritClass extends AbstractClass<Integer> {


}
```

Lets do simple test

```
package inherit;

/**
 * TODO: Add comment
 *
 * @author Ruslan Ibragimov
 */
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        testClass.test(new InheritClass());
    }

    private AbstractClass test(AbstractClass aClass) {
        for (String string : aClass.getStrings()) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
        return aClass;
    }
}


Make output:

Error:(16, 51) java: incompatible types
required: java.lang.String
found:    java.lang.Object
for (String string : aClass.getStrings()) {
```

Why this happens?

Comment: I don't think so, because `getStrings()` returns `Set<String>`

Comment: I bet if you declare `AbstractClass<?>` with unbounded wildcard then your code will probably compile.

Comment: @Joe, no i explicitly specify the type: "private Set<String> strings = ..."

Comment: @MenoHochschild, right, i know that, but why i need do this.

Comment: The raw type erases not only the generic parameter but also all other generic types so that `Set<String>` becomes `Set`. It is explained here: [Why won't this generic java code compile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662191/why-wont-this-generic-java-code-compile)

Comment: @Radiodef yes, this is answer. Write answer, and i accept him.

Comment: Thanks @Radiodef. I understood it now. I have taken down my answer to avoid any kind misunderstanding.

Comment: Can you try with `private Set<String> strings = new HashSet<String>();` instead of `new HashSet<>();`

Comment: @suninsky http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html i use jdk1.7

Comment: Thank you @IRus and learned a new thing of jdk 7

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
private AbstractClass test(AbstractClass aClass) {
```

use

```
private AbstractClass test(AbstractClass<? extends Integer> aClass) {
```

which will fix compiler and if you check return value of getStrings() in code assist, you will see Set intend of Set. Could be handy also read link provided by Radiodef in comments.

Comment: ```AbstractClass<?>``` better, and this is not essence of the question.

Comment: @IRus, I though you need to fix that, that's why that answer.