# How To Ensure the Validity of Parameterized Types Prior to Object Instantiation

Tags: java, generics, type-safety, raw-types

While studying Item 23 of Effective Java 2nd Edition I decided to attempt instantiating an object with a constructor that has a raw collection with an argument list of mixed objects. I assumed the compiler would pick up that I was attempting to pass a raw type to the constructor. However, the compiler only provides an unchecked exception warning, "at the caller, not the callee."

The class compiles fine, further supporting the statements by Josh Bloch not to use raw types in new code. The fact this compiles is a bit disturbing to me.

Q? How can one ensure the type safety of a class prior to instantiating the object short of having to manually check for object validity in the constructor? The following only provided an unchecked assignment warning from "the caller... in main" How could one defensively program against this.

```
public class RawType {

    private final Collection<Example> example;

    public RawType( Collection<Example> example ) {
        this.example = example;
    }

    public Collection<Example> getExample() {
        return example;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Collection unsafe = new ArrayList();

        unsafe.add( new Example() );
        unsafe.add( new Corruption() );
        unsafe.add( new Example() );

        RawType rawType = new RawType( unsafe ); // Corruption

        for(Object type : rawType.getExample()) {
            System.out.println(type.getClass().getName()); // Mixed Classes...
        }

    }

    static class Corruption {}

    static class Example{}

}
```

Comment: Don't ignore the warnings to avoid such situation.

Comment: The warning is not at the "callee" (the constructor) since there is nothing wrong with it. The problem is at the caller, where you are using raw type where you should use proper generic type. For the warning to be also at the callee side, it would have to say "this constructor/method is not used correctly somewhere else" and that just doesn't make sence.

Comment: I clearly stated, "The Caller. In main" Consider you're building an API and someone sends a raw type... How can you defensively program against it without manual validation. That is the question.

Comment: I shouldn't worry about it. Every Java programmer should know that using raw types is at their own risk, and if their program doesn't work because of it, it is their fault, not yours. Also note that vast majority of classes / APIs also don't protect against raw arguments.

Comment: "Many APIs also don't protect against raw arguments" ... Never thought of that... interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below lines compile but generate warnings as well.

```
Collection unsafe = new ArrayList(); // RAW type
unsafe.add(1);                       // no compile time error (just warning)

Collection<String> example = unsafe; // assign RAW type to parametrized type
example.add(1);                      // compile time error
```

Better use Generic collection to avoid such situation then add the values in it. **Never** mix [RAW](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) and parametrized type.

---

Have a look at below code:

```
Collection<Integer> unsafe = new ArrayList<Integer>();
unsafe.add(1);
Collection<String> example = unsafe; // compile time error
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400690/assigning-list-of-integer-into-a-list-of-string/25400917#25400917)

---

If you can't avoid RAW type then use below code in the constructor:

```
Collection unsafe = new ArrayList(); 
unsafe.add(1);                       
unsafe.add("hello");

// in the constructor, just add String values from the unsafe collection
Collection<String> example = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for(Object value:unsafe){
    if(value instanceof String){
        example.add((String)value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What I'm attempting to understand is, how I can ensure that the 'caller' doesn't send a foreign type in the argument? It seems to be impossible to force compliance without a validation implementation.

Comment: Why are you using RAW type? can you avoid it?

Comment: Generic works only for compile time check. All Generic type information are lost at run-time.

Comment: Yes, this isn't production... this is a review of [Item 23 Effective Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/bloch-effective-08-qa-140880.html) Don't use raw types...

Answer (score 0):

In order to make java generics compatible with code written before they were introduced, you can use an untyped collection anywhere that a typed collection is expected. So a Collection (with no type parameter) can be passed to a constructor that expects a Collection.

So in answer to your collection, you can only be safe by being careful when you add objects to an untyped colelction. If you want runtime sadfety you can manually validate the type of objects as you retreive them from the collection.