# Java8 type generic erasures methods signature and lambdas are not working

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

The best way to explain this is with the example:

```
public class Cosmos<T> {
    public void says(Consumer<String> stringConsumer) {
        stringConsumer.accept("we can");
    }
}
```

I was expecting this would work:

```
new Cosmos().says(s -> System.out.println(s.length()));
```

But **NO**, this is NOT working! Java8 thinks `s` is an `Object`!

However, if I define the `T` with *anything*, it works:

```
new Cosmos<Void>().says(s -> System.out.println(s.length()));
```

How comes the methods signature is related to generic type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't this generic java code compile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662191/why-wont-this-generic-java-code-compile)

Comment: It's because of raw types. If you create a raw Cosmos instance, all generic uses within its class definition are also raw usages. So actually you are callsing `says(Consumer)` instead of `says(Consumer<String>)`.

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings and *pay attention to them.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole concept of *raw types* was introduced for compatibility with pre-Generics code and consequently, using a *raw type* will effectively turn Generics off for *all* uses of this type, whether the generic signatures are related to the type’s declared type parameters or not.

This can be illustrated by the followed code example, which produces a compilation error before Java 5 and continues to produce a compilation error:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
String[] str = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

in contrast to the generic code

```
ArrayList<Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>();
String[] str = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

which can be compiled without errors, showing that the type parameters of `toArray` and the `List` are unrelated (a limitation of the generic type system).

Likewise, when you use `new Cosmos()`, the result is a *raw type* and invoking `says` on it will not use the generic type signature. But you don’t need to specify an actual type:

```
new Cosmos<>().says(s -> System.out.println(s.length()));
```

will compile without errors.

Comment: what about `public <S extends CharSequence> void says2(S s)`. Shouldn't the generics be erased in this case also and S become an Object? This does not compile: `new Cosmos().says2(new Object());`

Comment: @Eugene: the erasure is the first type of the upper bound, i.e. for `<S extends CharSequence>`, `S` becomes `CharSequence`, like it would for `<S extends CharSequence&Serializable>`, whereas for `<S extends Serializable&CharSequence>`, the erasure would be `Serializable`. And for `<S extends Object&CharSequence&Serializable>`, the erasure would be `Object`, …

Comment: … which is interesting for methods like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadataFormatImpl.html#addObjectValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-T-java.lang.Comparable-java.lang.Comparable-boolean-boolean-), whose erasure has to be compatible with its [pregenerics signature](https://web.archive.org/web/20121209203056/http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadataFormatImpl.html#addObjectValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Comparable,%20java.lang.Comparable,%20boolean,%20boolean)).

Comment: that is... I don't even know how to put it (I am getting slowly out of positive adjectives reading your answers). Thank you for the valuable input.